# Ruby on Rails converting date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime-select

I'm using html5 datetime-local type

```
<input type="datetime-local" value="" name="start_date1"/>
```

it sends this to the controller: 
2015-04-03T00:00

is it possible to convert it to this: 
2015-04-03 00:00:00 +0100

Comment: Can you explain what mean convert? where you need this convert? For what?

Comment: I have to convert this in controller, because I need to store it in database. and there i need this format: `2015-04-03 00:00:00 +0100`

Comment: Your database column have `datetime` type?

Comment: yes exactly column is `datetime`

Comment: use `strftime ` after getting  `params[start_date1]` and then save the record.

Comment: can you show me an example? do I have to do something like that `Time.new.strftime(params[start_date1])` -> dosn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try changing `params[start_date1]` to the datetime:

```
require 'date' # not needed if you're using Rails
params[start_date1] = DateTime.strptime(params[start_date1], '%Y-%m-%dT%R')
```

Here:

> %Y - Year with century (can be negative, 4 digits at least).
>
> %m - Month of the year, zero-padded (01..12).
>
> %d - Day of the month, zero-padded (01..31).
>
> %R - 24-hour time (%H:%M).

Your params value "2015-04-03T00:00" is parsed with '%Y-%m-%dT%R' because, %Y is 2015, %m is 04, %d is 03, "T" tells that time is in 24 hours format. So, we'd just put it as is, and use %R to parse "hours:minutes".

You can read more about `DateTime` [format directives here](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime).

Comment: thanks, but when I do this: I got this: `2015-04-15T01:59:00+00:00`

but I need this: `2015-04-15 01:59:00 +0100`, I need datetime as result

Comment: @Felix : It's `DateTime` object, which you can format later as per your convenience. Lookup the methods for formatting it `2015-04-15 01:59:00 +0100`. Shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: your right thats no problem :) Thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry for asking again, with puts it is printed correctliy in shell, but while storing it dosn't work corretly. puts says this: `2015-04-13 02:04:00` and in database its this: `2015-04-13 00:04:00` any idea whats going wrong? My code looks like this: `@datetime = @datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00")`

Comment: thanks it works now. just `@datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:00")` is the solution

Comment: @Felix : I am glad that you've sorted it out yourself. That's the spirit, and I encourage you to keep it that way. Otherwise you won't be able to learn things by yourself. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 1):

In Rails you should set your app's default time zone in `config.time_zone`. Then

```
Time.zone.parse(params[:start_date1])
```

will default to that time zone.

`Time.zone` can be overridden in runtime, see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-i-parse

You should also have a look at this: http://www.elabs.se/blog/36-working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Rails, check out: github.com/launchpadlab/decanter

The basic idea is that this gem provides a place for you to transform your params before they hit your model. Kind of like the inverse of Active Model Serializers.